# Unable to "npm install"

Tags: npm, electron, zip

Please could I ask for help with the following:

I have cloned the Electron starter app like so:

git clone https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start

And have it running.

I am working from the terminal window is VSCode.

I am using node version 6.13.4

Can type "npm start" and all is good, app runs fine.

Now, I want to use a certain package for working with zip files, so I try the following:

npm install decompress-zip

The result is ultimately an error, here's the output:

```
PS C:\Work\Electron Apps\electron-quick-start-added-fs-and-zip> npm install decompress-zip

> electron@16.0.5 postinstall C:\Work\Electron Apps\electron-quick-start-added-fs-and-zip\node_modules\electron
> node install.js

RequestError: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Work\Electron Apps\electron-quick-start-added-fs-and-zip\node_modules\got\source\request-as-event-emitter.js:178:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:428:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:333:22)
    at ClientRequest.origin.emit (C:\Work\Electron Apps\electron-quick-start-added-fs-and-zip\node_modules\@szmarczak\http-timer\source\index.js:37:11)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:321:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
npm WARN rollback Rolling back debug@2.6.9 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Work\Electron Apps\electron-quick-start-added-fs-and-zip\node_modules\extract-zip\node_modules'npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! electron@16.0.5 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the electron@16.0.5 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.       

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\105043131\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-05T11_15_47_499Z-debug.log
```

Now the build is broken. If try again "npm start" then I get:

> PS C:\Work\Electron Apps\electron-quick-start-added-fs-and-zip> npm
> start
>
> > electron-quick-start@1.0.0 start C:\Work\Electron Apps\electron-quick-start-added-fs-and-zip
> > electron .
>
> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984   throw err;   ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Work\Electron
> Apps\electron-quick-start-added-fs-and-zip\node_modules\electron\cli.js'
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:981:15)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:27)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
> at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [] } npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm
> ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! electron-quick-start@1.0.0 start: `electron .`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the
> electron-quick-start@1.0.0 start script. npm ERR! This is probably not
> a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\105043131\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2022-01-05T11_18_31_473Z-debug.log

Makes no difference now if I run "npm uninstall decompress-zip", I still get the same error when I try "npm start".

This line from the above caught my eye:

> npm ERR! Failed at the electron@16.0.5

If I start completely over an try installing another package instead like so:

> npm install yauzl

I get similar errors including the line:

```
npm ERR! Failed at the electron@16.0.5 postinstall script.
```

I currently have electron 8.1.1 installed

Could it be that these packages require electron 16?

Or is it something else?

If it is the former, would anyone know of a solution for unzipping a disk file using an older version of electron?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: In what way do you have Electron 8.1.1 installed? Looking at the Quick Start project's `package.json`, it specifically requires Electron 16 and above. Also, do you use any proxy or wire-tapping software? It seems there's a problem with NPM opening an encrypted connection to the package registry. Please check whether you can access `npmjs.com` without problems in your browser. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to update Node.js. Uninstall old version then go to https://nodejs.org/en/download/ and download LTC version

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately this didn't solve the issue.